# Uncaught Error: Error serializing unrecognized object about a date in react

Tags: date, reactjs, datepicker, runtime-error, redux-form

i use a react-datepicker which i adjust to be compatible with redux form. My Datepicker component is like this:

```
const MyDatePicker = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <DatePicker
      {...input} dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
      selected={input.value ? moment(input.value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') : null}
    />
    {
      touched && error &&
      <span className="error">
        {error}
      </span>
    }
  </div>
);
```

By the way it does not show the validation messages when i trigger a validation.
When i enter a date in a date input like the screenshot above:
[image]
an error is shown multiple times (5789 to be more accurate). That has the impact of making my app slow when i use dates. I google it but i didn't find a proper solution. Do you have any idea how to handle this? The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Error serializing unrecognized object Sun Mar 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200
    at b.rep (index.js:143)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.marshal (transit.js:2912)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.emitObjects (transit.js:2755)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.emitArray (transit.js:2765)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.marshal (transit.js:2930)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.emitTaggedMap (transit.js:2892)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.emitEncoded (transit.js:2909)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.marshal (transit.js:2934)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.emitObjects (transit.js:2755)
    at Object.com.cognitect.transit.impl.writer.emitArray
```

Last but not least i use REDUX-FORM/IMMUTABLE

Answer (score 2):

I am too getting same issue. My code look like.

```
<Container>
  {label && <Label icon={icon}>{label}</Label>}
  <DatePickerPure
    onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}
    // onChange={(val) => input.onChange(val ? val.toDate(val) : null)}
    onChange={(val) => input.onChange(val ? moment(val) : null)}
    selected={dateValue}
    id={`field_${input.name}`}
    placeholder={placeholder}
  />
  <FieldError touched={touched} error={error} warning={warning} />
 </Container>
```

In beginning date Filed was not picking correct date for the very 1st time. It was always picking 1 previous day. As soon as I use momnet(val), date field picking correct date but i m getting this error in my console. 
If any body can help